# iOS 12. OnDemand resources return NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.ondemand.client"

Tags: ios, objective-c, ondemand, on-demand-resources

Has anyone encountered this error? What is the reason for this?

My resource named "Tag" contained in "Prefetched" and "Download Only On Demand".

XCode 10 (10A255), iOS 12, IPhone 6 Plus.

My code:

```
NSSet *tags = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Tag", nil];
NSBundleResourceRequest *request = [[NSBundleResourceRequest alloc] initWithTags:tags];

[request conditionallyBeginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL resourcesAvailable) {
    if (resourcesAvailable)
    {
        /* some actions */
        [request endAccessingResources];
    }
    else
    {
        [request beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error)
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
            /* some actions */
            [request endAccessingResources];
        }];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Could be some temporary issue - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7560670